# How can I calculate the normal of a cone face in openGL 4.5?

Tags: java, jogl, opengl-4

I'm new at openGL 4.5 and I currently working with lights and it's all okay when I calculate vertex normals during the geometry drawing, but now I have to calculate face's normal for a cone and I have no idea on how to do it. I'm drawing it with GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP. We can see the current snippet below:

```
    float coneAngle = (float) Math.atan(radius / height);

    coneCos = (float) Math.cos(coneAngle);
    coneSin = (float) Math.sin(coneAngle);

    // circleResolution * heightResolution * 3

    for(int i = 0; i <= circleResolution; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j <= heightResolution; j++)
        {
            angle = 2 * ((float) Math.PI) * (i / (float) circleResolution);

            cos = ((float) Math.cos(angle));
            sin = ((float) Math.sin(angle));

            x = radius * cos;
            z = radius * sin;

            // Cone Bottom
            vertices.add(x);
            vertices.add(0.0f);
            vertices.add(z);                

            // Cone Bottom Normal
            vertices.add(coneCos * cos);
            vertices.add(coneSin);
            vertices.add(coneCos * sin);

            // Cone Top
            vertices.add(0f);
            vertices.add(height);
            vertices.add(0f);               

            // Cone Top Normal
            vertices.add(0f);
            vertices.add(0f);
            vertices.add(0f);
        }
    }

    // Center of Bottom Circle - Vertices
    vertices.add(0.0f);
    vertices.add(0.0f);
    vertices.add(0.0f);

    // Center of Bottom Circle - Normal
    vertices.add(0.0f);
    vertices.add(-1.0f);
    vertices.add(0.0f);

    // CircleResolution - Bottom Circle - TRIANGLE_FAN
    for (int j = 0; j <= circleResolution; j++)
    {
        angle = (2 * ((float) Math.PI)) * ( j / (float) circleResolution );

        x = (float) Math.cos(angle);
        z = (float) Math.sin(angle);

        vertices.add(radius * x);
        vertices.add(0.0f);
        vertices.add(radius * z);

        // Normal
        vertices.add(0.0f);
        vertices.add(-1.0f);
        vertices.add(0.0f);
    }
```

Polygon That Approximates a Cone
[image: Polygon That Approximates a Cone]

Comment: Do cones have faces?  You mean a polygon that approximates a cone?  Please be exact.

Comment: Yes, I mean polygon that approximates a cone. I added a picture of my current polygon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The normal vector to a line or (vetor) can be achiefed by a 90° rotation of a vector along the line.

[image: cone normal]

A vector along the flank of the cone is *(`radius`, `-height`)*. The normal vector is *(`-(-height)`, `radius`)*.

In your case the normal vector attribute of the flank of the cone, for the bottom ("Cone Bottom Normal") and top ("Cone Top Normal") vertices is:

```
// lenght of the flank of the cone
float flank_len = Math.sqrt(radius*radius + height*height); 

// unit vector along the flank of the cone
float cone_x = radius / flank_len; 
float cone_y = -height / flank_len;

.....

// Cone Bottom Normal
vertices.add(-cone_y * cos);
vertices.add( cone_x );
vertices.add(-cone_y * sin);

.....

// Cone Top Normal
vertices.add(-cone_y * cos);
vertices.add( cone_x );
vertices.add(-cone_y * sin);
```

Comment: Also given any triangle, the normal can be found as the cross product of two vectors that lie in the plane of the triangle.  Pick the end points of the triangle and subtract to form a vector that lies in the plane.

Comment: @markspace Yes that is what the [Cross product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product) does